# CSS style sheet not loading all selectors

Tags: html, css

I am working on a personal website using flask for development.This is my stylesheet style.css

```
<style>
.red-text{
  color: rgb(255,0,0);
  padding: 20;
}
/*color of unselected tabs and left navigation menu*/
.navigator-color{
  background-color: rgb(33,37,43);
}
.display_color{
  background-color: rgb(40,44,52);
}
.selected-tab{
  background-color: rgb(42,46,54);
}
.text-color{
  color:rgb(183.186,193);
}
.highlight_color{
  background-color: rgb(86,138,242);
}
/* - - edit, I had incorrect comment, but I added in my question and it wasn't in my actual style sheet-- this should change h2 to blue, but it doesnt */
h2{color:rgb(0,0,255)}
</style>
```

and this is from the developer view when the site is running on Chrome in incognito mode (to keep the site from caching):
Sources->Top->localhost:5000->static/css->style.css
my h2 style was completely stripped.

```
.red-text{
  color: rgb(255,0,0);
  padding: 20;
}

/*color of unselected tabs and left navigation menu*/
.navigator-color{
  background-color: rgb(33,37,43);
}
.display_color{
  background-color: rgb(40,44,52);
}
.selected-tab{
  background-color: rgb(42,46,54);
}
.text-color{
  color:rgb(183.186,193);
}
.highlight_color{
  background-color: rgb(86,138,242);
}
```

For some reason it will load in styling by class definitions but it won't load in styling by element or id (not included, but same result, I pulled everything out trying to get this to work.)

I really don't understand what the issue is and am hitting my head against a brick wall for the last 3 hours.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favico.png') }}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="red-text">THIS WILL CHANGE THE COLOR</h1>
      <h2>THE COLOR REMAINS UNCHANGED</h2>
    </header>

    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use <!-- .... --> style comments in CSS. Could that be it?

Comment: This might have just been a copy error, but look at your `.text-color` class. You have a period instead of a comma

Comment: If you're not using an IDE that checks for CSS errors, run your code through [W3's css validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: And `<style>` and `</style>` don't belong into an external stylesheet either - those are _HTML_ tags.

Comment: This is just poorly written CSS. You need to go back and review it before posting here.

Comment: The incorrect commenting was added as I wrote my question and isn't in my actual css sheet, I've fixed this in my answer.

Comment: However the period in the text-color class was definitely my error. Sharp eyes, thanks.

Comment: Then the problem is probably still the <style> and </style> tags inside your css file, as stated above, if you haven't removed those.

Comment: I'm at work but I will try it out when I get a chance. Thanks for the quick responses, guys

Comment: Webfrogs was the most correct. Stepping away I started back from scratch. Things are working much smoother now. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.red-text{
  color: rgb(255,0,0);
  padding: 20;
}
/*color of unselected tabs and left navigation menu*/
.navigator-color{
  background-color: rgb(33,37,43);
}
.display_color{
  background-color: rgb(40,44,52);
}
.selected-tab{
  background-color: rgb(42,46,54);
}
.text-color{
  color:rgb(183.186,193);
}
.highlight_color{
  background-color: rgb(86,138,242);
}
/* this should change h2 to blue, and now it probably does */
h2{color:rgb(0,0,255)}
```

Edit: Changes made: Replaced the  style comments with /* ... */ style comments, and removed `<style>` tags from the stylesheet.